# enum causes this "The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

Tags: java, enums

I need your help.
I am writing a code for an assignment and I wanted to create a enum method like this:

```
public enum Color{
RED, BLUE, WHITE, GREEN
}
```

I also tried to do it like this:

```
enum Color{
RED, BLUE, WHITE, GREEN
}
```

In both cases the following error appears: " The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

How can I fix this? As additional data I do not know if this is important but I am using DR.Java to code

Comment: Are you using an IDE? It seems like the IDE can't find the JRE libraries. What happens if you compile from the command line? `javac your/package/Color.java` should compile.

Comment: I do not what IDE I am using, I guess is the default one that comes with DR. Java. The error message appears no matter what I do. When I erase the lines of code for enum the message disappears, but I need to use enum.

Comment: I suggest you to use a better IDE.. What about trying Eclipse or IntelliJ?